# Setup MySQL on a Mac

Tags: mac, mysql

How can I set up a MySQL server on my MacBook Pro? I already used Homebrew to install MySQL, but now I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

[Dan Benjamin](http://twitter.com/danbenjamin) created some tutorials on [his site](http://hivelogic.com/):

[INSTALLING MYSQL ON MAC OS X](http://hivelogic.com/articles/installing-mysql-on-mac-os-x/)

[INSTALLING MYSQL ON SNOW LEOPARD](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard/)

Don't write directly to him with support requests or questions.

Comment: I guess if he has questions, he can ask them here!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the quick-and-dirty approach, use XAMPP. That installs a complete LAMP stack on your laptop including a graphical interface for starting/stopping the different elements. See: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html